# Can't seem to override a CSS property (margin-right)?

Tags: css

I have a really basic list in HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="navmenu">
    <ul>
    <li>photography</li>
    <li>&#149</li>
    <li>people</li>
    <li>places</li>
    <li>things</li>
    <li id="lastElement">about</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS formatting looks like this:

```
div#navmenu li {
     display: inline;
     margin-right: 40px;
}
```

However, I want the last li element's margin-right be 0px. So I did:

```
li#lastElement {
     margin-right: 0px;
}
```

When I check on Chrome's dev tools, this last CSS specification is crossed out. I don't understand why it's overridden by the "div#nav menu li" property? Isn't the last li element with its own id more specific?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one that is overriding it is more specific, it has two tag and an id selector, while your other only has a tag and id selector.

You could change it to `div#navmenu li#lastElement` *or* make the other selector less specific.

Comment: So if two CSS specifications target the same element, it comes down to the absolute count of id selectors and then tags?

Answer (score 1):

Hi now used to this

```
div#navmenu #lastElement {
     margin-right: 0px;
}
```

or this

```
div#navmenu li:last-child {
     margin-right: 0px;
}
```